# How to Deattach permissions from a role? (in laravel Freamwork and entrust package.)

Tags: laravel, entrust

i working whith entrust package in laravel for management roles and permissions.

```
$role->deattachPermission($permission);
```

its not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of options:

`$role->perms()->sync([]);`

Or

`$role->perms()->detach($permission)`

Answer (score 2):

`$role->perms()->detach($permission->id);`